# Can anyone help me manually construct a http request for this rest based webservice?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a REST based WCF web-service;

The contract is:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
string EchoWithPost(string message);
```

The message is:

```
public string EchoWithPost(string s)
{
    return "ECHO with POST : You said " + s;
}
```

I used the web channel factory to get a response via POST and it works. I used wireshark to tap the message and I can see some important things:

1) That xml is sent
2) The Content Type

From this I have constructed the following request logic:

```
        //5) manually post to the REST service
        //Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlOfService + "/rest/EchoWithPOST");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.


        string postData = "&lt;EchoWithPost xmlns=&quot;http://tempuri.org&quot;&gt;&lt;message&gt;Hello&lt;/message&gt;&lt;EchoWithPost&gt;";



        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

However when I hit the line that says:

> dataStream =
>   response.GetResponseStream();

I get the following error:

"The remote server returned an error : (400) Bad Request"

Could someone help me with what I need to do as I need to be able to tell people how to manually create a POST request to interact with this REST based service.

Any help much appreciated dont really see what else I can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few small changes, so I'll just post the entire thing.  Hopefully it works for you.  Also, I didn't add any deserializing, figuring you could tackle that as long as you make it past the HTTP 400 error.

A great tool to help you debug these situations is SoapUI.  Just setup a "Web TestCase", and you can create your own POST requests and monitor the data that's going back and forth.

-Vito

Interface:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "EchoWithPost", Method="POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    string EchoWithPost(string message);
```

Service:

```
    public string EchoWithPost(string s)
    {
        return "ECHO with POST : You said " + s;
    }
```

Client:

```
string urlOfService = "http://somewhere.com/RestService.svc/EchoWithPost";
string postData = "<EchoWithPost xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><message>Vito</message></EchoWithPost>";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlOfService);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/xml;";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();

// Output raw string result
string rawStringResult = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("\r\n" + rawStringResult);
```

web.config:

Comment: Hi Vito, this worked, basically I looked through both code sections and all I needed to take out was clean up the xml so thanks. I am going to get SOAP UI and play around with it because I just cant get fiddler working

Answer (score 1):

If the content type says that you're sending XML, then you shouldn't escape your XML to send it to the service - at least not the wrapping of the message; if you had some characters which needed escaping in the content (text), then you'd need to escape them. Change postData to the line below, and it should work.

```
string postData = "<EchoWithPost xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org\"><message>Hello &amp; goodbye</message></EchoWithPost>";
```

Comment: Hi Carols I tried it with escaping and without escaping neither worked. Ill keep your idea in mind if I find what the actual problem is it could cause me an issue further down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Download this tool http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

try to call the rest method and see the raw data(request response) in fiddler, you will get the exact info about the error

Answer (score 0):

Well Pete2k, I would say that without running your service it could take some time to reconstruct this.  Are you using the WCF 4.0 REST Project?  If so it has a help page that should show you what the request data looks like.